# How to handle reoccurring request parameters in swagger yaml

Tags: node.js, swagger, backend

Is there a way to define all the reoccurring request parameters in one place as we do with schemas. For example

```
parameters:
- name: auth
  in: header
  description: an authorization header
  required: true
  type: string
- name: id
  in: header
  description: an special id
  required: true
  type: string
```

These headers are required in all APIs so please let me know if there's such a way so we don't have to write them in all the APIs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [$ref keyword](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/).

Comment: I didn't know it can be used within parameters. Thanks.